# Can FTDI Basic Breakout and FTDI XBee Explorer USB be used alternatively?

Tags: usb, serial, communication, ftdi, sparkfun

I wonder if these two boards from sparkfun can be used alternatively for USB to Serial communication?

The first: (FTDI Basic Breakout)

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9716

The second: (FTDI XBee Explorer USB )

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11812

Thank you

Comment: Can you precise something for me? You want to know if you can use both boards for a XBEE application right?

Comment: No, I already have FTDI XBee Explorer USB.

In another project, I needed to built a custom board for controlling 8 servo motors but the board needs FTDI Basic Breakout. So, I wanted to know if there's a way to use the one I have already instead of purchasing a the new. 
Thank you.

Comment: the first option is more generic. The second option is more specific to XBEE.

Answer (score 1):

The first link is a simple dev kit for the FTDI chip FTDI FT232RL. You can get the details [here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT232R.htm). You can use that dev kit to communicate with your PC via Serial on MCU side and USB on PC side.

The second option seem to be more specific for XBEE communication.